# How to determine KDE versions on a remote system accessed via SSH?

Tags: ssh, terminal, kde

I need to regularly know some software version numbers of remote machines that I access via SSH.

The commands that I would use to get these software version numbers are:

```
plasmashell --version
konsole --version
```

and sometimes:

```
qtdiag
```

The error I get is:

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
>   qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.

The command 'echo $DISPLAY' returns nothing

I do not believe I want to do X-Forwarding via SSH. I am accessing a machine that is running X (KDE). If I run 'qtdiag' I only want info about that machine, not about my local X.

I also do not need to see any GUI output. For example, running 'plasmashell --version' in a local terminal produces the following terminal output:

> plasmashell 5.16.4

I don't need to see the GUI to see that output in the terminal. I would like to do the same when I connect to a remote machine.

Comment: I guess they all check for $DISPLAY before they check their options and since it's not set they quit. You probably should try with -X and see if that works. In any case, when you run an X application on a remote machine, it runs on that machine (it just uses your X for display), so the information pertains to that machine, not yours

Comment: I cannot change sshd_config on some of the remote systems, therefore, I cannot enable X11Forwarding. Even if I could, it would not be good for the security of my system.